# CSS style sheet defined style not translating to the HTML web page on demo (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2017

I added CSS for a div tag at the bottom of the form body of a webpage in a file called `StyleSheet1.css` It is in the same folder as the webpage. For some reason, only the new CSS (for div tag with id="contact_popup") I added for the new div tag at the bottom of the form is not showing when I demo the webpage. The rest of `StyleSheet1.css` is working though and showing when I demo it.

Within `StyleSheet1.css`, I tried defining the CSS via both `#contact_popup` and div `#contact_pop` . The new CSS I added did not show on the webpage in either case. When adding the link to the web page, I tried both `href = "StyleSheet1.css" and "~/StyleSheet1.css"`, neither case worked for the new CSS. I also tried putting that new div tag just outside and below the end of the form, but that didn't work either.

Here's how I added the script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
```

Here's where I placed the new div tag at the bottom of the form:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
<div id="contact_popup">asdfasdf</div>
</form>
```

Here's the new CSS I added for the div tag:

```
#contact-popup {
    color:red;
    width:100%;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your id is "contact_popup" in your style sheet your wrote "contact-popup"

Comment: Where is your stylesheet file in relation to your html file? Are they in the same directory?

Comment: I fixed the typo. But its still not working

Comment: The style sheet is in the same directory as the webpage

Comment: check the console if there is  any error then make sure you delete the Cache from your browser

Answer (score 0):

The ID defined in css file is #contact-popup, while the div ID defined in the HTML file is contact_popup

Comment: Try to close the input tag,  / at the end is missing

Comment: I tried this as well <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" style="margin-bottom:20px;"/> But it did not work

Comment: Can you post the start tag of <form>?

Comment: <form name="property_review" method="post">

Comment: unfortunately I need that as I am extracting information from many questions throughout the form. The reason for the div tag is to create a popup message when when a user reaches the end of the page.

Comment: Check weather in the css file, before and after your div css, there are some weird characters

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there. You id is called "contact_popup" but you select with "#contact-popup".
Try "#contact_popup" instead.

```
#contact_popup {
    color:red;
    width:100%;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

Edit: I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nrqtcua/) for your case. As you can see it works there if you fix the selector. If it still doesn't work maybe you did someting wrong with attaching your StyleSheet1.css OR another rule of your css is overwriting the desired behavior.

Comment: Here are all the links to style sheets in my header tags on the webpage:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin.css">

Comment: Can you post/link all of your css in StyleSheet1.css?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `!important` to each attribute in your css.

Answer (score 0):

**list of some reasons why a css file  is not working**

1- Are you sure the stylesheet is loaded? You can see it using the "Net" tab of Firebug on firefox, or on "Network" tab of the Console of your browser.alse you can Copy the css file's url and paste it into your browser. If it doesn't load the file than you know the problem is in the url.

2- Any typo inside your HTML or CSS stylesheet may cause the stylesheet from loading.like your id and class name

3- Check for any occurrences of fatal errors before your  tag. A fatal error may stop the running code and suspend the page, thus not including your stylesheet.

4- Could it be that you have an error in your CSS file ? A parenthesis left unclosed, a missing semicolon etc?